# Unwanted ios Scrollbar when Body has 100vh

Tags: html, css

I have a great script. It is a CSS3 animation. Here is the CSS of the body... if I have nothing else on the page, but just the body, there is still an unwanted scrollbar that appears on mobile. I do not want a scrollbar on mobile1 It goes away when I set the `body {height:90vh}` but then it looks like crap on a browser.

Here's my CSS:

```
body  {
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
    font-family: 'Lato',  Arial,  sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    overflow: hidden !important;
     margin: 0 !important;
 }
```

Basically, is there a way I can set the `body height` to be that of the actual view minus all the other bottom and top bars, something using `window.screen.availHeight;` or something like that?

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please see my latest revision.

Comment: @Jonathan Safa did my solution worked for you?

Comment: Rajendran, I already know where the issue is... it is in the body... Like I said, if I comment absolutely everything on the page, there is still the issue... There isn't a div that is causing the extra space. It is the iPhone rendering the top and bottom nav.

Comment: Which browser? Safari? Can you put an image?

Answer (score -1):

There is a really good trick to find which element is causing the overflow.
Put this piece of code in you stylesheet.

```
* {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**What is going on?**

This will add a border to all elements you can see which element is going out of the viewport like a div or maybe a heading tag or a paragraph tag.

**How to fix the overflow?**

open up the inspect element hover on all the elements do some trial and error by adding width/height property.

Hope this will help you to fix the issue. If you need a fiddler please let me know I will add an example.